# JDK and joda-time dateformatter: how to consider day light savings time

Tags: java, jodatime, date-format, simpledateformat

@Jon Skeet, I downloaded Joda-Time as you recommended in, [Date parsing/formatting with TimeZone and SimpleDateFormat give different results around DST switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356672/date-parsing-formating-with-timezone-and-simpledateformat-problem-around-dst-swi), and added it to my Java EE / JSF project, attempted to use DateTime and DateTimeFormatter, and they are returning the same result as JDK 6 (see below), since it is now Day Light Savings here in EST timezone (US/Eastern).

ORDER #  0739  Trip Date 11/11/2011 to **11/12/2011**  Customer # 1004

Trip Date/Time: 11/11/2011 05:00 PM
Report Date/Time: 11/11/2011 04:45 PM
**Return** Date/Time: **11/13/2011 02:00 AM**

Code is as follows:

```
public String getDateFromDateTime (Date date, Boolean display) throws ParseException {

    /*
     * SimpleDateFormat working as designed, but pf_ordersController.selected.returnDateTime displaying incorrect date/time
     * 
     * see below from /orders/pf_View.xhtml
     * pf_ordersController.selected.returnDateTime (displayed on JSF page) = 11/13/2011 02:00 AM
     * 
     * ORDER #  0739  Trip Date 11/11/2011 to 11/12/2011  Customer # 1004
     * 
     * Trip Date/Time: 11/11/2011 05:00 PM  Report Date/Time: 11/11/2011 04:45 PM   Return Date/Time: 11/13/2011 02:00 AM
     * 
     * orders.returnDateTime (stored in database) = 11/12/2011 21:00:00 (9:00 PM)
     * SimpleDateFormat converts orders.returnDateTime to 11/12/2011 (working as designed)
     * 
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356672/date-parsing-formating-with-timezone-and-simpledateformat-problem-around-dst-swi
     * 
    DateFormat formatter;
    String myDate;

    if (display)
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    else
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    myDate = formatter.format(date);
     * 
     */

    DateTimeFormatter dtFormatter;

    if (display)
        dtFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    else
        dtFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
    String myDate = dt.toString(dtFormatter);

    System.out.println("OrderDisplayUtil.java:getDateFromDateTime(" + date + ", " + display + "): " + "myDate = " + myDate);

    return myDate;

}
```

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: As orien said, we need to know how you got your input. I don't mind whether it's in the form of a unit test or a short but complete console app, but something I can run either way :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for your quick response. I just confirmed that SimpleDateFormat is working as designed, because the problem date/time is the Orders.returnDateTime, which is passed to this method, getDateFromDateTime(Orders.returnDateTime, ...).  Orders.returnDateTime = 2011-11-12 21:00:00, but my JSF/controller code is displaying 2011-11-13 02:00:00 for some reason.  I will continue looking at this.  By the way, thanks for letting me know how I should ask questions; i'm sure you can already tell that i'm a newbie here. :)

Comment: For more suggestions around asking a good question, see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. It sounds like you have *lots* of conversions going on in your code. Isolate them one by one, and work out *exactly* where the problem is.

Comment: @JonSkeet, you're right, I do have lots of conversions, and I'm wondering if it's too much for JSF.  I have a tripDateTime, reportDateTime, and returnDateTime.  I finally decided to use Joda-Time (DateTime) to return a formatted date-string, since the returnDateTime value is correct when passing it around in the beans, but JSF xhtml was NOT displaying the value correct at all. The bean returns the formatted date-string to JSF xhtml, and that solves my problem.  Thanks again for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be specific with your explanation of the problems you're having with your method. What are your input values what do expect as your output values. As a developer you should be expressing this in the form of a test.

```
@Test
public void testGetDateFromDateTime() {
    DateTimeZone timezone = DateTimeZone.forID("US/Eastern");
    Date date = new DateTime(2011, 11, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, timezone).toDate();

    String formattedDate = unitUnderTest.getDateFromDateTime(date, true);

    Assert.assertEquals(formattedDate, "11/11/2011");
}
```

Your problem is you are not explicitly specifying the timezone you want to format your date. In this case Java will take the timezone set on the operating system running the JVM. So for instance, if you want to format the date/time 2011/11/11 16:45 from US/Eastern on a system running in Singapore, using the +08:00 timezone. The system will interpret the date/time as 2011/11/12 06:00, which represents the exact same moment in time. The system will then use the formatter and give '11/12/2011'.

Let's resolve this issue by specifying the timezone you wish to use:

```
public String getDateFromDateTime(Date date, Boolean display) {

    DateTimeFormatter dtFormatter;

    if (display)
        dtFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    else
        dtFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("US/Eastern");
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(date, timeZone);
    String myDate = dt.toString(dtFormatter);

    return myDate;
}
```

Also note that US daylight savings time ended on November 6.

Comment: thanks for the answer/response and the code modification/recommendation.  As I mentioned above to JonSkeet, I learned that SimpleDateFormat is working as designed; i need to debug my JSF/controller logic and confirm why Orders.returnDateTime is not the correct date/time for this Orders record/row.  Everywhere else, this Orders.returnDateTime is display correctly, but not when I display the date via OrdersController.selected.returnDateTime; the xhtml is working as designed for other rows, but not for this one. Should I update the question here, since i mis-stated earlier? thanks again.

Comment: oh, i forgot to mention, right now, the target endusers will most likely be using this web app behind a network firewall, for my family.  The date/time values will always be based on personnel that is using the web app in the office, so localDateTime meets requirement for now. Honestly, I cannot think of a use case where this business requirement will need to consider TimeZone.  Thanks again.