# How to convert date and time to est format in android?

Tags: java, android, timezone

Here is my code.

```
public String getDateTime()
{


    String dateAndTime = 

    (new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa")).format(new Date());

    return dateAndTime;


}

public String getDate()
{

        android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
        String Date = df.format("MM-dd-yyyy", new java.util.Date()).toString();

        return  Date;
}
```

I have searched about this. but, i cant find the perfect answer. Please help me.

Comment: Danger - time zone abbreviations like `EST` can be ambiguous!  `EST` isn't as dangerous as others, like `CST` which might mean "Central Standard Time", or "China Standard Time"!  [See this list](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/)

Comment: EST can be dangerous enough if your time happens to fall in the time of year when summer time (DST) in effect (which is the greater part of the year). Then you won’t know whether this will be taken into consideration or not, since the correct three letter abbreviation would have been EDT (which in turn *is*  ambiguous, it may also refer to Australian Eastern Daylight Time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below function

```
    private Date shiftTimeZone(Date date, TimeZone sourceTimeZone, TimeZone targetTimeZone) {
    Calendar sourceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    sourceCalendar.setTime(date);
    sourceCalendar.setTimeZone(sourceTimeZone);

    Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (int field : new int[] {Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.MILLISECOND}) {
        targetCalendar.set(field, sourceCalendar.get(field));
    }
    targetCalendar.setTimeZone(targetTimeZone);
    System.out.println("........"+targetCalendar.getTimeZone());
    return targetCalendar.getTime();
  }
```

Usage:

```
    Date date= new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sf.format(date);
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT") OR TimeZone tz =  sf.getTimeZone();      
    TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");     
    Date c= shiftTimeZone( date,tz,tz1);
    System.out.println("Format :   " + sf.format(c));
```

Output
            sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="EST",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

```
    Format :   01-05-2013 16:23:57
```

Comment: @Nirmal did u try the above?

Comment: s. but i din't get the exact things. I got an output from here dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java. thanks for your effort dude.

Comment: @Nirmal what do you mean by "din't get the exact things".?

Comment: it returns exactly. but here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java it gives the simple code.

Comment: @Nirmal thanks for accepting. The above code give u time and date in EST format

Comment: its ok..
public String getDate()
 {
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm aaa");       sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
final String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());       
return  utcTime;
}
this code is enough to do this process. anyway Thanks For your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer here :

[Date and time conversion to some other Timezone in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429357/date-and-time-conversion-to-some-other-timezone-in-java)

You have to use `TimeZone` class and Calendar class.

Get current time :

```
Calendar currentdatetime = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Just pass your time zone name in `TimeZone` class like this :

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
```

Use `DateFormater`

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Then format your time like this :

```
formatter.setTimeZone(obj);
```

and get output like this :

```
System.out.println("EST Time is : "+ formatter.format(currentdatetime .getTime())
```

Comment: DateFormat is not supporting for this method dude. Thanks for your effort