# How to convert a time from GMT to EST

Tags: java, android, date, timezone, java-time

I have a Date & time "20140508063630" in (yyyyMMddHHmmss) format. I want to convert this Time into EST time zone. How can I do it? If there is any API for this conversion please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could be the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313087/how-to-convert-date-and-time-to-est-format-in-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

Comment: [There](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694885/timezones-in-java) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429357/date-and-time-conversion-to-some-other-timezone-in-java) [dozens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java) [of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion) AND answers about converting between time zones in general and even between specific time zones.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin So vote to close the question.

Comment: The first thing i did.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin No, you didn't apparently. The "close" count is zero (at this moment… I'm about to vote to close myself). You may have clicked the "flag" link rather than the "close" link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    try {
          DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
          TimeZone estTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
          gmtFormat.setTimeZone(estTime);
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
          sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
          System.out.println("EST Time: " + gmtFormat.format(sdf.parse("20140508063630")));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This is not GMT to EST this ans is for my timezone to EST .. because you are creating new date, not using existing date which i have

Comment: @Sameer Kazi: I'm assuming that im in GMT. Just for example i took current date. User can use any date and format in GMT. This answer just to explain how to convert from GMT to EST.

Comment: I parse date string (20140508063630) into date and them using your code. it not doing anything.

Comment: @Ashish Tiwari: I have edited the code. Can you follow the updated code?

Comment: @Ashish Tiwari Accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged your question java-time, you do deserve a `java.time` answer.

```
    String dateAndTime = "20140508063630";
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    ZonedDateTime coralHarbourDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTime, parseFormatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Coral_Harbour"));
    System.out.println(coralHarbourDateTime);
```

This prints

```
2014-05-08T01:36:30-05:00[America/Coral_Harbour]
```

There are a number of things to note though:

- You also tagged your question android. `java.time` seems to be coming to Android, but as of writing it is not on the majority of Android phones. Don’ t despair, though, get the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and use the classes on Android.
- The `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone` classes used in the other answers are long outdated, so if your Android app is doing any work with dates and/or times and/or time zones, I do recommend ThreeTenABP and the modern classes as the programmer friendly and the futureproof way to go.
- You asked for EST time zone and then gave us a date of May 8, which is in the summer time (DST) part of the year. First, three letter abbreviations are dangerous in being ambiguous and in this case not a full time zone, so avoid them where you can. I solved the problem by using America/Coral_Harbour since I read that this particular place uses EST all year round, no summer time. If this was not what you intended, please provide a different location. If instead I use America/Montreal, I get `2014-05-08T02:36:30-04:00[America/Montreal]`, for example, with time zone offset -4 instead of -5.

**Furhter link:** [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

Answer (score 1):

Following code for convert date from one timezone to another timezone with any date format

```
{   String parsedDate = null;

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    dbDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date date = dbUtcDateFormat.parse("20140508063630");

        SimpleDateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyyMMddHHmmss);
        userDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        parsedDate = userDateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.warn("Date Parse Faied : ", t);
    }

    return parsedDate;
}
```