# How to handle time zone difference between server and native android application?

Tags: android, timezone, android-date

Suppose that my server located in USA and I live in Russia. We know that they have different time zones.

My application getting text(`String`) from server. And this text data has `Date` column in database to keep record date.

When I get data, I also get `date` knowledge. So I can group them by time. First ones at the top and last ones at the bottom. Whatever...

I wrote a function to show date value more human-readable such as "13 hours", "9 minutes". Server sends me the date in server's (USA) time zone.

When I calculate time on application with Russia time zone (because it's current time zone on application), it calculates wrong. So, it's not stuff what anybody wants.

What should I do to achieve the correct calculation?

**Annotation:** This application will be used by different countries' citizens. So I can't make the calculation static.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't really such as thing as "Russia time zone" or "USA time zone".  Both of those countries have several different time zones.  See the Wikipedia articles on [Time in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia) and [Time in the USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_States).

You should always write server code such that it is not dependent on the time zone that the server is running in.  Usually this is done by storing all time as [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).  Since the client is an Android device, just convert to and from local time on the client, sending just UTC to/from the server.

If you're working in Java, you should probably use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for your conversions.  It is much cleaner and easier to use than the `Calendar` class.

**Update**

As Basil pointed out in comments, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the `java.time` classes defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). For earlier Android, see the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) projects. See [How to use…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Does this UTC conversion handles daylight savings?

Comment: @vishnu - UTC does not have any daylight saving time, but when you convert to *local time*, DST will be taken into account  (assuming you're using the APIs correctly and not trying to adjust for DST manually).

Comment: Joda-Time home page has moved. Updated the link.

Comment: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes defined by [*JSR 310*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). For earlier Android, see the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) projects. See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 2):

The Calendar class can convert times between timezones, so long as you know what timezone the server and the client use.  To avoid problems in the future if you ever move the server, its best to define what the time in the database should be.  I prefer to use UTC for this as its standard, but you can use any timezone you wish, so long as its defined and in your documentation so you'll know in the future.

Here's a question that shows how to do it:  [Date and time conversion to some other Timezone in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429357/date-and-time-conversion-to-some-other-timezone-in-java)

Comment: The troublesome `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted years ago the java.time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque Java.time is android 8, which just got added to Android about a month ago, and is only supported on v26+.  It won't be safe for common use on android for at least 3, and more likely 5 years depending on how much of the market you're willing to drop  support for.

Comment: For earlier Android, see the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) projects. See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: @BasilBourque No thanks.  I don't need to add more random libraries to my project to get minor functionality when there's existing solutions.  I'm not adding the security risk.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Time zone is irrelevant for elapsed hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Duration.between(
    Instant.parse( "2017-12-14T01:34:56.123456789Z" ) ;
    Instant.now() 
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the industry-leading *java.time* classes. These supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`.

Servers should generally be set to a time zone of UTC. And you should never depend on any such setting. Instead, your code should specify the desired/expected time zone.

Your business logic, data storage, and data exchange should all be in UTC as a general rule. When serializing to text, use the standard ISO 8601 formats only.

Apply other time zones when necessary, as when expected by a user in the user interface. So generally you should think of time zones other than UTC as a localization issue.

### `Instant`

The `Instant` class represents a moment, a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. Getting the current moment is unaffected by time zone settings.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Serializing to text in standard format by calling `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

You can exchange an `Instant` with your database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myPreparedStatement.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

To generate strings in non-standard formats, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Search Stack Overflow for many examples and discussions.

### `Duration`

To get the number of hours, minutes, seconds elapsed, use the `Duration` class. Note that **you do not need time zones for elapsed time**; UTC (`Instant`) gives the same result.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( then , Instant.now() ) ;
```

For earlier Android, see the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) projects. See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how this can be achieved in a programmatic way but i know it can be done :) ...
maybe you should try a strategy where you save all your records according to GMT time then on your client side make a formula where it checks the time zone of the client then if it was a negative time zone substitute that amount from the current time record and if it was a positive time zone add that amount to the time record this way it will show to the client according to there time zone ..... ( excuse my grammar :) wish it could )

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in Java prior to Java 8, you should probably use Joda Time for your conversions. Take a look at this question: [Date and time conversion to some other Timezone in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9429357/1429387)

If you're working in Java 8 and newer (or if you plan to start the upgrade process in your company), Java 8 includes a proper Date/Time library and the creators of Joda recommend switching to using that. Take a look at this question: [Joda Time - Convert UTC DateTime to Date - Using a Version 1.2.1.1 of Joda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32658205/1429387)

Comment: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project has been in maintenance mode for years. The team advises migration to the java.time classes defined by [*JSR 310*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). For earlier Android, see the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) projects. See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).