# Convert yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz format Strin to date object

Tags: java, nsdateformatter

I have a `GMT` formatted String value in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz`

`eg: 2013-07-29 06:35:40:622 GMT.`
I want to get it as a date object and convert it into `IST` time zone.

I did smthng like this...
     **

```
    String GMT = "2013-07-29 06:35:40:622 GMT";  
     DateFormat utcDateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
     utcDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    try {
        utcDateFormat.parse(GMT);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }**
```

bt gettng error as java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-07-29 06:35:40:622 GMT"

Comment: Start by checking out [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and having a read of the other few hundred posts on the same subject...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date and time conversion to some other Timezone in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429357/date-and-time-conversion-to-some-other-timezone-in-java)

Comment: Try JodaTime. It is much easier to use.

Comment: Try this might help you, SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  String dateInMyFormat sdf.format(new Date());

Comment: What have you *tried*?

Comment: I think the `zzz` format doesn't recognize the `GMT` text

Comment: Got it ..It was my mistake.  I gave it as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz"   instead of "ss:SSS"    Thanks for ur replies :)

Answer (score 8):

The main (problems) are that `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't recognize the text `GMT`, it's looking for a different format for the time zone.

The other problem is your format doesn't match your text...

Your `String` is in the form of

```
2013-07-29 06:35:40:622 GMT
```

And your format is in the form of

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz
                   ^--------This is a naughty character...
```

The seconds and milliseconds are separated by different characters, this isn't going to help

Now, if we fix the expected format with the actual format, this won't fix the issue with the time zone...but, fourtantly for us, `DateFormat` provides a [`lenient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) method, this allows us to "bend" the format rules a bit...

So, with all that in hand, you can try something like...

```
String text = "2013-07-29 06:35:40:622 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
sdf.setTimeZone(gmt);
sdf.setLenient(false);

try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(text);
    System.out.println(date);

    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Mon Jul 29 16:35:40 EST 2013
2013-07-29 06:35:40:622
```

Comment: After changing it to the actual format I got it correctly..but i didnt include dat linient method..nyway i was not aware of this method earlier.. thnks for this information..

Comment: I'd be curious as to why this answer would deserver a downvote? In what ways does it not answer the question been asked - remember, it was answered 2013, so the never APIs weren't available, or is jus that you don't think the question should have been answered? Shame on me for wanting to help someone

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```
Date d=new Date("2013-07-29 06:35:40:622");
Date newDate=new Date(d.getYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate());
Time t=new Time(d.getHours()+5, d.getMinutes()+30, d.getSeconds());
```

Comment: All those methods are depreciated, not even sure why you'd bother with `java.sql.Time`...

Comment: Got it ..It was my mistake. I gave it as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz" instead of "ss:SSS"     Thanks for ur replies :)

Answer (score -1):

Joda Time supports timezone conversion.  http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Changing_TimeZone