# java Date to sencha Date using dateFormatter

Tags: java, date, extjs, date-formatting

I need Date strings sent to sencha frontend of the form:

> 'Wed Jan 10 2007 15:05:01 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)'

I'm unable to get the right text formatter string to output in this form. 
Has anyone converted a Java Date object to this format ?

PS: not a duplicate of [time lag while converting between timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429357/date-and-time-conversion-to-some-other-timezone-in-java),

Its a query to get Dates in a specific format required for frontends using sencha which isn't answered by the "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" format used in this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format pattern you need:

```
"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzzzzz)"
```