# Parsing time stamp strings from a different time zone

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a String with timestamp in GMT. I want to convert this to a DateTime object in EST.
E.g If the string has:
`final String gmtTime = "20140917-18:55:25"; // 4:55 PM GMT`
I need to convert this to : 20140917-12:55:25 //12:55 PM EST

All these tries failed:

```
    System.out.println("Time in GMT " + DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime(gmtTime));

    System.out.println("Time in EST " +
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime(gmtTime).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")));
```

Output:
Time in GMT 2014-09-17T18:55:25.000-04:00
Time in EST 2014-09-17T18:55:25.000-04:00 //I expect: 2014-09-17T12:55:25.000-04:00

Any suggestions?

Comment: "18:55:25; // 4:55 PM GMT" - That 6:55 PM or 16:55 ... or not gmt ;)

Comment: Try reading this, might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9429592/2902209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Joda-Time

Here a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4 solution:

```
String gmtTime = "20140917-18:55:25";
DateTime dateTimeGMT =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss").withZoneUTC().parseDateTime(gmtTime);
System.out.println("Time in GMT " + dateTimeGMT); // Time in GMT 2014-09-17T18:55:25.000Z

System.out.println(
    "Time in EST "
    + DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss").withZone(
        DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")
    ).print(dateTimeGMT)
); //Time in EST 20140917-14:55:25
```

I think that you have the wrong expectation regarding the result. EST (more correct to use is "America/New_York" as [zone identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)) is four hours behind UTC, hence the local timestamp there is four hours earlier than the local representation of the same moment at UTC-offset.

Also note that I set the timezone on the formatter not on the parsed `DateTime`-object.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void TimeZoneTest() {

    Date now = new Date();

    String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss";

    DateFormat dfEST = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN);
    dfEST.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    DateFormat dfGMT = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN);
    dfGMT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    System.out.println(dfEST.format(now));
    System.out.println(dfGMT.format(now));

}
```

And the output is:

```
20140919-09:02:19
20140919-13:02:19
```